# If $_1,_2$ are eigenvectors of $A$ with different eigenvalues $λ_1 \neq λ_2$, show that $1 + 2$ is not an eigenvector of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

$Av_1 = λ_1v_1$ and $Av_2 = λ_2v_2$

Adding both equations:
$$A(v_1+v_2) = λ_1v_1 + λ_2v_2$$
since $λ_1$ not equal to $λ_2$, $(v_1+v_2)$ has no common eigenvalue $λ$ thus $v_1+v_2$ is not an eigenvector of $A$.

how exactly to prove this? can you help modify the proof?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $A(v_1+v_2)=\lambda_3(v_1+v_2)$. Then 
$$0=A(v_1+v_2)-Av_1-Av_2=\lambda_3(v_1+v_2)-\lambda_1v_1-\lambda_2v_2=(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)v_1+(\lambda_3-\lambda_2)v_2. $$
As $\lambda_3-\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_3-\lambda_2$ cannot both be zero, this shows $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent. But then their eigenvalues must be the same ...

Answer (score 1):

Since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are two eigenvectors with different eigenvalues they are linearly independent. Now suppose by contradiction that $v_1+v_2$ is also an eigenvector of $A$. This means that there exists $\mu\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A(v_1+v_2)=\mu(v_1+v_2)$, that is
$$
\mu v_1 + \mu v_2 = A(v_1+v_2)=Av_1+ Av_2 = \lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2.
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
(\lambda_1-\mu)v_1 + (\lambda_2-\mu)v_2=0,
$$
and by linear independence it follows that $\lambda_1=\mu=\lambda_2$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues are always linearly independent. If we had $$A(v_1+v_2)=\lambda(v_1+v_2)=\lambda v_1+\lambda_2,$$we would also have$$A(v_1+v_2)=Av_1+AV-2=\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2$$and therefore $(\lambda_1-\lambda)v_1+(\lambda_2-\lambda)v_2=0$. But the numbers $\lambda_1-\lambda$ and $\lambda_2-\lambda$ cannot both be equal to $0$ and this contradites the linear independence of $v_1$ and $v_2$.